# JUnit test - division by zero. Java

Tags: java, testing, methods, junit

```
public void div( int i )
{
    acc = acc / i;
}
```

I want to make a test for this method. I did test for integers different than 0. But i have problem with test when `i=0`. Can you tell me how it should look?

Answer (score 5):

When you divide by zero, then you will receive `java.lang.ArithmeticException.class`. You can create a unit test that will accept this exception. E.g.

```
 @Test(expected=java.lang.ArithmeticException.class)
    public void testDivideByZero() {
           acc = acc / i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes across this problem, division by 0 was giving infinity as a result. I came across this solution.

```
@Test
    public void testDivideByZero() {
        double resultDiv = mCalculator.div(3, 0);
        assertEquals("Divide by zero gives infinity as result", true, Double.isInfinite(resultDiv));
    }
```